# batch file to name folder based on filename

Tags: batch-file

I have managed to copy and manipulate a batch script that does the following:

- looks at the last 4 characters of a .csv file
- creates a folder with this name
- moves the file into the folder

  ```
  @echo off & setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
  echo.
  pushd "%~dp0"
  for %%j in (*.csv) do (
      set file=%%~nj
      set folder=!file:~-4!
      if !folder!==FI_2 set folder=!file:~-6!
      if not exist !folder! md !folder!
      move "%%~j" "!folder!"
  echo "%%~j" -^> "!folder!"
  )
  popd
  echo.& echo.Done

  :: End_Of_Batch
  ```

The problem I have is that I need to group the files by month.  The file names look like this:

```
BS_IDX_LEVEL_YYYYMMDD_BAFI.csv
```

(obviously the YYYYMMDD will be replaced with the date of the file)

So any file with the name BS_IDX_LEVEL_20111231_BAFI.csv would go into a folder named "1112" (date formate of folder is YYMM)
A file with the name BS_IDX_LEVEL_20111115_BAFI.csv would go into a folder names "1111"

Is there someway I can alter this script so that before organising the files by their filenames it groups them by date first?

If I can explain anything further please let me know

Comment: Is the `BS_IDX_LEVEL_` part of the name fixed?

Answer (score 0):

While you are looping through and getting the last 4 characters of the file name, you can also look at the dates. I didn't know if the start of the file will be fixed or subject to change, but I thought it reasonable to assume the date_end syntax would be consistent.

```
set filedate=!file:~-9,-7!
```

This will extract the characters between 9th and 7th from the end of the String stored in `!file!`.  With the syntax you have, the will be the two digit month number. This will also avoid any confusion with 2 or 4 digit dates.

Once you have both this and the other folder name, you can simply create both folders at once and place the file directly into the subfolder, so you will still only need to make one pass over the fileset.

```
@echo off & setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
echo.
pushd "%~dp0"
for %%j in (*.csv) do (
    set file=%%~nj
    set folder=!file:~-4!
    if !folder!==FI_2 set folder=!file:~-6!
    set filedate=!file:~-9,-7!
    SET datefolder=!folder!\!filedate!
    if not exist !folder! md !folder!
    if not exist !folder!\!filedate! md !folder!\!filedate!
    move "%%~j" "!datefolder!"
echo "%%~j" -^> "!datefolder!"
)
popd
echo.& echo.Done

:: End_Of_Batch
```